# Snowflake: Is there a way to create a warehouse without using it?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

We're using [DBT](https://www.getdbt.com/) to run automated CI/CD to provision all our resources in Snowflake, including databases, schemas, users, roles, warehouses, etc.

The issue comes up when we're creating warehouses -- the active warehouse automatically switches over to the newly created one. And this happens whether or not the warehouse already exists (we're using `CREATE WAREHOUSE IF NOT EXISTS` commands).

This basically resumes/turns on all our warehouses for no reason (even though we're using `INITIALLY_SUSPENDED = TRUE`), because snowflake is then using that warehouse to execute the subsequent queries. And then our CI/CD continues on the wrong warehouse (whichever one was the last one to execute). We have a dedicated warehouse for CI/CD, and we'd like the execution to remain on that one (so we can monitor the costs).

We're aware that this is the default behavior specified [in the documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-warehouse.html#usage-notes), but **is there any way to create a warehouse without using it?**

I wish the `CREATE WAREHOUSE` command had a parameter like `USE_WAREHOUSE = TRUE|FALSE`.

As a workaround, we're exploring ways to skip the `CREATE WAREHOUSE` commands entirely if the warehouse already exists, but that doesn't solve the issue for warehouses that do need to be created.

Otherwise, we might just add a `USE WAREHOUSE` command after every `CREATE WAREHOUSE`, in order to return to the original CI/CD warehouse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to store current warehouse in a variable and restore it:

```
SET warehouse_name = (SELECT CURRENT_WAREHOUSE());

CREATE WAREHOUSE TEST WAREHOUSE_SIZE=XSMALL, INITIALLY_SUSPENDED=TRUE;

USE WAREHOUSE IDENTIFIER($warehouse_name);
```

---

Alternatively wrapping it with stored procedure(simplified version - no error handling and only warehouse name provided as parameter):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE create_warehouse(CURRENT_WAREHOUSE_NAME STRING
                                            ,WAREHOUSE_NAME STRING)
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE javascript
AS
$$
 var rs = snowflake.execute({sqlText: `CREATE WAREHOUSE IF NOT EXISTS IDENTIFIER(?) WAREHOUSE_SIZE=MEDIUM, INITIALLY_SUSPENDED=TRUE`, binds:[WAREHOUSE_NAME]});   
 // restore original warehouse, USE WAREHOUSE cannot be used inside SP
 var rs2 = snowflake.execute({sqlText:`CREATE WAREHOUSE IF NOT EXISTS IDENTIFIER(?)`, binds:[CURRENT_WAREHOUSE_NAME]});   
 return 'Done.';
$$;

CALL create_warehouse(CURRENT_WAREHOUSE(), 'TEST');
```

Comment: Yup, this is the way!  Fortunately, I can hardcode or programmatically determine the name of the CI warehouse from the current DBT profile (so no need to store it in a SQL variable).

Answer (score 0):

The [Snowflake docs](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-warehouse.html) describe an `INITIALLY_SUSPENDED` property, defaulting FALSE, which specifies whether the warehouse should be created initially in Suspended state.

I think you should set that property `TRUE` in your script.

Comment: In addition, there's this point: `and continues our CI/CD on the wrong warehouse (whichever one was the last one to execute)`. Snowflake will set session context to the most recently created database, schema and warehouse. In your CI/CD script, you can run `use warehouse original_warehouse` after you create a new one so that it's set back to the one you want.

Comment: @Schepo: We're already doing this. That's not the problem. The problem is that Snowflake will automatically `USE` the warehouse as the current warehouse going forward, and resume it automatically in order to execute the subsequent queries -- even though it was created with `INITIALLY_SUSPENDED = TRUE`.